# How can I select STATUS as an array? It's json_decode data

Tags: php, json, laravel

```
{
   "OUTPUT": {"STATUS": "SUCCESS"},
   "TransactionId": "548535330959430"
}
```

How can I select STATUS as an array? It's json_decode data.

Comment: Do you mean `$json["OUTPUT"][0]`?

Comment: If I select TransactionId, it would be be $json-> TransactionId
Now I would like to select STATUS